# Why this div is between two other nested divs? z-index related

Tags: css, position, positioning, z-index

The best way to explain this is via example:
http://jsfiddle.net/e7JjU/

I have a pretty good understanding of z-indexes and the stacking context but I cannot figure out a logical reason div1 (blue) is able to appear between the stacks of red and green. Can someone please explain this?

```
#div1{ 
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#div2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    background-color: red;
}
#inner{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    left: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

and the HTML...

```
<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="div2">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>​
​
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? the Red div doesn't have a `z-index`; the blue `z-index:1;` is taking precedence and will be visible over the red. But the green has `z-index:2` so it will be visible over both.

Comment: Because z-indexes are supposed to be compared against siblings. So the z-index on div1 should be compared to div2, putting 1 on top. I would expect this to make children of div2 to appear UNDER div1 as well. Here is an example showing the expected behavior in a similar way: http://jsfiddle.net/7wUzz/

Comment: but comparing div1 to its sibling div2, div1 has a z-index of 1, while div2 does not. give div2 a z-index of 1 also, and then it will be on top of div1..OR...remove the z-index from div1

Comment: So if a sibling has no z-index at all and you're comparing against it, it will use the z-index of the highest child... am I understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your red div, `#div2` doesnt have a z-index. But `#div1` and `#inner` do. If you were to put the z-index on `#div2` then the blue div would not appear between the green div and red div.

z-index applies to the parent divs and child divs.

```
<div id="div1" style="z-index:1"></div>


<div id="div2" style="z-index:2">
   <div id="div4" style="z-index:4;"><!--Higher than any of the other divs--></div>
</div>

<div id="div3 style="z-index:3">
    <div><!-- any div inside div3 are higher than div1 and div2 but not div4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track but you have the wrong conclusion. In your example, children of div3 would be above div4 because div3 is compared against it's sibling div2. When sibling parents both have z-indexes, children z-indexes are only used inside their parents stacking context. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wYaNK/

Comment: Thanks for that! I did not know that. I know that if `#div2` didnt have a z-index at all, then `#div3` would be above `#div3`. Is that right?  http://jsfiddle.net/wYaNK/1/

Comment: Right... z-indexes and nested elements can definitely get more complex than I had realized until recently. =/  I came across this page that seems to explain things fairly well (I've only skimmed it so far): http://eng.wealthfront.com/2010/03/z-index-and-local-stacking-contexts.html